# How do I count the number of occurrences in a big data file that occur on a number of filters, one of which is an OR statement?

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace

I can easily count on filters from the data like this 
-->

```
=count(filter(Data!$A$2:$A, Data!$C$2:$C=$C13,Data!$E$2:$E=$A$5,Data!$J$2:$J>=P$7))
```

But I want

```
Data! Data!$E$2:$E=$A$5 Or $A$6 Or $A$7
```

... but an Or statement gives an error. What is the way to do this? I can't lose the rest of my filters either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the + operator, which works just like boolean OR, thanks to 0 being interpreted as boolean false and non-zero as true:

```
=count(filter(Data!$A$2:$A, (Data!$C$2:$C=$C13) + (Data!$E$2:$E=$A$5) + (Data!$J$2:$J>=P$7)))
```