# How to add arrayformula function to this formula with IF function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I made a table that has two columns (namd & State). The 4th column(check) makes conditional formatting possible for any of these combinations: (if name is either "Ali" or "John", AND state is "FL"), a conditional formatting rule is applied only if the cell value of E2 is "NO".

I had to repeat this formula for all rows and I failed to wrap it in an arrayformula function.

I tried this but failed:
`=if(OR(AND(C2="John",D2="FL",$E$1="No"),AND(C2="Ali",D2="FL",$E$1="No")),1,0)`

adding arrayformula:
`=ArrayFormula(if(OR(AND(C2:C="John",C2:D="FL",$E$1="No"),AND(C2:C="Ali",D2:D="FL",$E$1="No")),1,0))`

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17mmduo0em4PK0FDPxIRTX36CqhW6woI4jdyPSJaiGAM/edit#gid=1414263054

Comment: Related:https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/42428/88163,  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/107662/88163, https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/117795/88163

Answer (score 0):

Aggregating functions such as `and()` and `or()` do not give row-by-row results in an `arrayformula()` wrapper, but they can be replaced with [Boolean arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-element_Boolean_algebra) like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  ((C2:C = "John") + (C2:C = "Ali"))
  * 
  ((D2:D = "FL") * (E1 = "No"))
)
```

Each equals test will return a `true` or `false`, and these values get coersed to `1` and `0` when arithmetic operators are used.